# Cloudflare worker local (dev) development cache is stuck?

Tags: caching, cloudflare-workers, wrangler

I'm experimenting locally with Cloudflare workers and wrangler (`> wrangler dev`). And after some time developing locally it seems the response is cached somewhere (non-local).

If I change the sources (`src/index.js`) wrangler reloads (and seems to detect issues if present), but the served page is not updated (and nothing is logged to console (with `console.log(...)`). Also new private browser windows does not help (so it seems not locally cached?)

I wonder what it could be, and how I can fix what I suspect is a (non-local) caching issue?